# How would I use sed to insert a character at a certain character position on only ONE line?

Tags: sed

I am aware that this will do what I want on all lines:

```
sed 's/^\(.\{4\}\)/\1-/' textFile
```

But how would I enter a - after the 4th character slot on ONLY the 5th line? Or even better, on a range of lines, like from 5-7?

Comment: for specific line no 4 : ` 4s` and for range: `5,7s` That's it

Answer (score 2):

The first part of a `sed` command is a range specification which indicates which line(s) you wish to affect. The default, if no range is specified, is all lines. So:

```
sed '5,7s/^\(.\{4\}\)/\1-/' textFile
```

should do what you want.